# How to install my USB to VGA adapter on linux? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, drivers, vga

I bought a USB 3.0 to VGA adapter (also comatible with 2.0)
and the driver that comes with is "FLUSBVGA-1.1.258.0 (1).exe" for Windows.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 / 14.04 and I can't find support for this adapter. T-T

In this FrescoLogic page, the last drivers for Windows are available.
http://www.frescologic.com/support.php

Does anyone knows what can I do to use it on Ubuntu?

Comment: Short answer: Unfortunately that device isn't compatible with Linux, get one that is.

Comment: You can reverse engineer the windows driver and write your own for Linux.  Other than that, no.

Comment: I already bought one of these. I wonder if anyone could do reverse engineer on that driver...

Comment: There is a basic driver of sorts, it displays a static image.  This is a start that could be turned into a fbdev or drm driver (to work with X and so on).  However, there is no framebuffer on the USB stick, the entire screen content is sent to the stick for each screen refresh (like 60-80 times per second...) and they found performance was problem